# Add New option not show up if custom post type included with submenu

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, submenu

I want to add my custom post type like in word press sub_menu page but it does't show Add New option on left side I don't know what am i doing wrong.

```
register_post_type( 'shortcode',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Shortcode' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'shortcode' ),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'show_in_menu' => false,
      'supports' => array('title'),
    )
  );
```

and that is my menu page code

```
add_menu_page( 'Review', 'Review', 'manage_options', 'options', array( $this->option, 'render_options' ), 'dashicons-admin-page', 99 );

    $custom_post_type = 'edit.php?post_type=shortcode';
    add_submenu_page('options', 'Link', 'Link', 'manage_options', $custom_post_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will automatically add a Menu item to the Administration panel for Custom Post Types, assuming the post type is set to public and show_ui is not set to false (defaults to the value of public).

So, the question becomes are you sure you are registering your custom post type correctly? You cannot just call the code directly. You need to register an init hook to take care of this.

```
add_action('init', 'register_my_custom_post_type');

function register_my_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'shortcode',
        array(
           'labels' => array(
           'name' => __( 'Shortcode' ),
           'singular_name' => __( 'shortcode' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'show_in_menu' => false,
        'supports' => array('title'),
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: yes i think i call it in right way and i also include the hook.

add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_type' ) );

Comment: Actually it works fine if i just include only custom post type but when i merge it with sub_menu_page its add new option not show on left side in admin menu.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish at this point.